# Get-AppxPackage still lists a program after Remove-AppxPackage & Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-store-app

I can successfully remove and de-provision Xbox with PowerShell like this

```
Get-AppxPackage -Name "*XboxApp*" | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage -Name "*XboxApp*" | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
```

However, even after a reboot

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Select Name
```

still lists XboxApp. I thought this would only list installed apps, so removing for all user should remove it from the list, much like uninstalling a program the old fashioned way removes it from the Uninstall registry key and from Add & Remove Programs. Am I not understanding the function of `Get-AppxPackage` here? FWIW, I am testing in 1703, does this behavior change in a more recent update?

Comment: Add `-AllUsers` option in left side of pipe of first command. Add `-online` option in both side of pipe of second command.

Comment: @biswapriyo -online with Get-AppXPackage throws an error for me, and adding -AllUsers to both sides of the pipe in the first line, and -online only on the right in the second, still leaves AboxApp in the list after the uninstall. I wonder, what build of Windows 10 are you doing this with?

Comment: I removed all of the installed packages :)

Comment: OK, are you saying it works for you? That brings us back to, what build of Windows 10 are you using? It's failing for me with 1703, and both PowerShell and the behavior of Windows/Micorosoft Store have changed since 1703 I think.

Comment: Latest insider build.

Comment: That makes sense. Maybe I just need to accept that older versions of Windows 10 are too buggy and broken to test against.

Comment: @Ramhound, from what I can see, in 1703 there is no way to uninstall some of the Microsoft crapware at all, as well as programs like Xbox can be uninstalled for everyone but still shows up as installed programs. Microsoft might call those features, but to my mind as an admin those are bugs. But I think I can accept that no one should really still be using something that old, and do my testing on newer version where I can actually uninstall this junk. I don't have every single build to test against and verify exactly when certain behavior changed.

Comment: @Ramhound Unless you re saying that BECAUSE 1703 is no longer supported this behavior changed to punish people who don't update, and it DID work when 1703 was still supported? That would be an interesting bit of knowledge.

Comment: But, from what I can tell there IS no way to uninstall this stuff in 1703. Changing is fine, but if its not possible that's not cool. Do you know of a technique that DOES work? I have no issues with two or three approaches over time, I just can't find any way to successfully remove Candy Crush Soda Saga or Bubble Witch 3 Saga, and I can't get Skype and Xbox to uninstall AND not show up in the list, which makes it hard to determine with automation which machines need them removed.

Comment: As for Start ++, can that be automated, or is that an option that allows users to fix their own machines? My goal is to allow an IT Manager to fix an offices professional machines. Some of this stuff has no business on a professional machine. And needing to install another program in order to get rid of junk that Microsoft never should have shoved down our throats is a but frustrating.

Comment: 90% of Architecture firms are using Windows 10 Pro, which is marketed as a profession OS. Just because a firm is only 10 people doesn't mean it's OK for Microsoft to play this BS game. But, as far as me providing support, knowing that older versions just couldn't do this, and newer versions can is enough to move forward with. Thanks for that! I know some firms also use Start++, so I'll need to look at that too. But most of the small ones have neither time or cost budget to install more and more apps, we are often installing as many as a hundreds apps already, just for actual professional work.

Comment: But, that's what I can't seem to find. A way to AUTOMATE that uninstall. The reality is that soooo many small architecture firms are running whatever crap their machine vendor installed, because as a 10 person firm with a part time IT person with an architecture background, that's all they can hope for. I am trying to help them not hate Windows any more, but Microsoft really seems to want small firms to have them. But, if you know of a way to automate that in older versions I would love to learn it!